# Change image when radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a form to measure carpets dimension. In the form there is radio button which user can choose type of carpet. I want to make when the radio button checked, the image of the carpet change based on the selected radio button.

1st image : radio button to choose carpet size

[image: radio button to choose carpet type]

2nd image: carpet change based on selected radio button

[image: carpet image change based on selected radio button]

Below is the code:

```
<form class="carpet-detail text-center container">
      <p class="text-center">Upload your carpet’s photo here :</p>
      <div class="upload-carpet">
        <div id="image-preview">
          <input id="image-upload" name="image" type="file">
        </div>
        <label for="image-upload" id="image-label">Choose File</label>
      </div>
      <p class="carpet-name">Carpet 1</p>
      <p>Choose your carpet shape :</p>
      <div class="carpet-shape">
        <div class="choose-carpet">
          <input checked class="radio-shape" id="carpet-shape-1" name="carpet-shape" type="radio"> <label class="choose-shape" for="carpet-shape-1">Rectangular</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choose-carpet">
          <input class="radio-shape" id="carpet-shape-2" name="carpet-shape" type="radio"> <label class="choose-shape" for="carpet-shape-2">Square</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choose-carpet">
          <input class="radio-shape" id="carpet-shape-3" name="carpet-shape" type="radio"> <label class="choose-shape" for="carpet-shape-3">Round</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choose-carpet">
          <input class="radio-shape" id="carpet-shape-4" name="carpet-shape" type="radio"> <label class="choose-shape" for="carpet-shape-4">Oval</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Please insert your carpet size :</p>
      <img alt="carpet rectangle" class="carpet-icon" height="116" src="img/icons/carpet-rectangle.svg" width="194">
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x carpet-size">
        <div class="small-6 cell text-left">
          <p>Width :</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 cell text-right">
          <p>/sqft</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 cell">
          <div class="input-group plus-minus-input">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <button type="button" class="button circle" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity-width">
                <img src="img/icons/size-minus.svg" alt="minus" width="11" height="11">
              </button>
            </div>
            <input class="input-group-field" type="number" name="quantity-width" value="0">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <button type="button" class="button circle" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity-width">
                <img src="img/icons/size-plus.svg" alt="minus" width="11" height="11">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x carpet-size">
        <div class="small-6 cell text-left">
          <p>Length :</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 cell text-right">
          <p>/sqft</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 cell">
          <div class="input-group plus-minus-input">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <button type="button" class="button circle" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity-length">
                <img src="img/icons/size-minus.svg" alt="minus" width="11" height="11">
              </button>
            </div>
            <input class="input-group-field" type="number" name="quantity-length" value="0">
            <div class="input-group-button">
              <button type="button" class="button circle" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity-length">
                <img src="img/icons/size-plus.svg" alt="plus" width="11" height="11">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Call JS function on the selection of radio button and perform operation inside JS function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery's `.change` event to do this. 
First assign the attribute `value`to the radios.

```
<input class="radio-shape" value="Square" id="carpet-shape-2" name="carpet-shape" type="radio">
```

Then use the change following juery to trigger the event.

```
$('input:radio[name="carpet-shape"]').change(
function(){
    var $src = "";
    if ($(this).val() == 'Square') {
        $src = "img/icons/carpet-square.svg";
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'Rectangle') {
        $src = "img/icons/carpet-rectangle.svg";
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == 'Round') {
        $src = "img/icons/carpet-round.svg";
    }
    else{
        $src = "img/icons/carpet-oval.svg"
    }

    $('.carpet-icon').attr('src',$src);

});
```

Here is a full working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obs7ks7n/)
For more information on `change` event, checkout the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a JavaScript or jQuery event listener.

```
//jQuery version
$('#radio1').on('click', function() {
  $('#image1').attr('src', 'myNewImage.jpg');
});

//Vanilla JavaScript
document.getElementById('radio1').addEventListener('click', null,
  function() {
    document.getElementsById('radio1').setAttribute('src', 'myNewImage.jpg');
});
```

You'd obviously need to add one for each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image by using **CSS** selectors like **`~`** , **`+`**.

By this method, if the checkbox is checked we can select the siblings by using the `~, +` selector.

Then we can apply the styles to the selected siblings.

Here I have given the code snippet and **working** demo.

**CSS CODE**

```
       .output-shape {
            width: 200px;
            }
//Square
         #square ~  .output-shape{
                width: 200px;
           }
//Rectangle
          #rectangle:checked ~   .output-shape{
                    width: 280px;
           }
//Circle
          #circle:checked ~   .output-shape{
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 200px;
           }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    // Input Field
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="circle" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rectangle">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="square">

   // Label Field
        <label for="circle">circle</label>
        <label for="rectangle">Rectangle</label>
        <label for="square">square</label>

   // OUTPUT    
        <div class="output-shape"></div>
```

**Working DEMO**

```css
 body, html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 }
 .box-overlay {
  background-color: coral;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 .box-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }

 .output-shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 input {
  display: none;
 }
 label {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
 }
 .option-name {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 
/* Circle */
 label[for="circle"] {
  color: dodgerblue;
  border-color: dodgerblue;
 }

 #circle:checked ~ .box-content [for="circle"] {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
 }
 #circle:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name{
  color: dodgerblue;
 }
 #circle:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name:before{
  content:"Circle" !important;
 }
 #circle:checked ~ .box-content .output .output-shape{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-color: dodgerblue;
 }
 #circle:checked ~ .box-overlay {
  background-color: dodgerblue !important;
  
 } 
 
/* Rectangle */
  label[for="rectangle"] {
  color: darkorange;
  border-color: darkorange;
 }
 
 #rectangle:checked ~ .box-content [for="rectangle"] {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: darkorange;
 }
  #rectangle:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name{
  color: darkorange;
 }
 #rectangle:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name:before{
  content:"rectangle" !important;
 }
 #rectangle:checked ~ .box-content .output .output-shape{
  width: 280px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border-color: darkorange;
  
 }
 #rectangle:checked ~ .box-overlay {
  background-color: darkorange !important;
  
 }
 
/* Square */
 label[for="square"] {
  color: #3FBB76;
  border-color: #3FBB76;
 }
 #square:checked ~ .box-content [for="square"] {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3FBB76;
 }
 #square:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name{
  color: #3FBB76;
 }
 #square:checked ~ .box-content .output .option-name:before{
  content:"square" !important;
 }
 #square:checked ~ .box-content .output .output-shape{
 background-color: #3FBB76;
  border-color: #3FBB76;
 }
 #square:checked ~ .box-overlay {
  background-color: #3FBB76 !important;
  
 } 
 .box-overlay, .output-shape, .option-name:before {
  transition: all linear 0.50s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.50s;
  -o-transition: all linear 0.50s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.50s;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
  .box-content {
   margin-top: 20px;
  }
 }
 @media (min-width: 769px) {
  body, html {
/*   height: 100%;*/
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>CSS Shape transition </title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="circle" checked>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rectangle">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="square">
 <div class="box-content">
 <label for="circle">circle</label>
 <label for="rectangle">Rectangle</label>
 <label for="square">square</label>
  <h4 class="output">
  You have selected
   <div class="output-shape"></div>
   <span class="option-name"></span>
  </h4>
  
 </div>
 <div class="box-overlay"></div>
 </div>
 

  
  </body>

</html>
```

Note: To achieve this input element need to present above to the image element.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to see which radio input was checked and then perform some changes on the icon image to show the desired image : I believe you are looking for something like the code below, I haven't tested it so you may
want to tweak it a little bit..

```
$('.carpet-detail').on('click', 'input', changeImage);
// delegate the the listening to the form so you don't have
// to listen to every radio button, then filter only radio
function changeImage(evt){
// create a function that can receive the event object by
// providing a parameter
  var imageId = evt.target.id;
// store the id of the target element in var
  switch(imageId){
// a simple switch statement to see which radio was checked
    case 'carpet-shape-2':
    $('.carpet-icon').attr("src","carpet-shape-2.jpg");
    break;
// set the correct image for the chosen radio
    case 'carpet-shape-3':
    $('.carpet-icon').attr("src","carpet-shape-3.jpg");
    break;
    case 'carpet-shape-4':
    $('.carpet-icon').attr("src","carpet-shape-4.jpg");
    default:
    $('.carpet-icon').attr("src","default-image.jpg");
  }
}
```